How i can change the shortcuts for a specific workspace in my case the Sculpting space
I only want change the shortcuts for my sculpting workspace so that the change of my shortcuts are not affecting the other.
In my case I want change the Pan view for only the sculpting workspace the other workspaces should not touch it.

Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is harder to read and may be considered rude. Please use the [edit] button below the post to change your text into regular case.

You can do this in the Preferences by adding a view3d.move keymap to Sculpt. Here are the steps:

Open the Preferences (Edit > Preferences) and click Keymap on left side.

Scroll down to the 3D View section, and expand it. Then, scroll down to the Sculpt section, and expand it. Finally, expand the Sculpt (Global) as shown below. This (3D View > Sculpt > Sculpt (Global))  is where the keymap should be added to only affect the 3D View while sculpting.




To add a new keymap to this section, scroll down to the bottom of the list where the Add New button can be found. Click this button to add a new none entry. Expand it to be able to customize it. Click the Identifier field and type view3d.move in it. This is the operator that pans the 3D View. Next, customize the button that will trigger the panning. I set it to the E key on the keyboard as shown below.


Now, while in Sculpt mode, holding the E key allows panning the view. This is limited to sculpting.
Note that the middle mouse button panning is still going to work while sculpting in addition to the E key. If you want to remove the middle mouse button keymap from sculpting, there are two options:

Remove that keymap from the 3D View > 3D View (Global) section. This will remove it from all modes which means that this keymap will need to be manually introduced to all modes other than sculpting.

Add a keymap to the 3D View > Sculpt > Sculpt (Global) section that uses the middle mouse button. This will shadow/override the 3D View > 3D View (Global) function.


